# Converting String date to Date object

Tags: javascript, date

I have a variable which is retrieved from php, and is stored in a variable called `activity.ActivityDate` . When I do a

```
console.log(activity.ActivityDate);
```

It outputs `14/06/2016` , which is a valid format which can be turned into a date object. But when I do

```
d = new Date(activity.ActivityDate);
console.log(d);
```

I get an invalid date. But when I do

```
e = new Date('14/06/2016');
console.log(e);
```

I do get a proper date object.

Is there something wrong with my `activity.ActivityDate` string, or some way to turn it into a proper string?

Comment: How about: `d = new Date(activity.ActivityDate.toString());`

Comment: The datestring in the `Date()` constructor expects a specific format, and it can depend on the broswer. For example while `MM/DD/YYYY` isn't defined in Chrome, but `DD/MM/YYYY` is. You would best off be splitting the values in the string and imputing them as integers in the proper fields of `new Date(year, month[, day[ ... )`.

Comment: @Hackerman still getting an invalid date

Comment: All right, then try: `d = new Date(activity.ActivityDate.toString().split('/').reverse().join('-'))` ...you can use `moment.js` too: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: @Hackerman nice, this works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different browsers can parse datestrings differently as noted by MDN it's discouraged to use the [`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor to parse a datestring. In your case you're giving the format `DD/MM/YYYY`, but it's likely your browser is expecting `MM/DD/YYYY`.

> Note: parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse, they are equivalent) is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies.

The best thing to do so it would work in all browsers would be to spilt your string by `"/"` and convert your numbers into integers then use the constructor format for the `Date(year, month, day)`  constructor.

For example:

```js
var date = '14/06/2016';
var items = date.split('/');
var day = +items[0];            // Note +(item) means convert to interger
var month= +(items[1] - 1);     // month goes from 0-11 rather than 1-12.
var year = +items[2];
e = new Date(year, month, day);
console.log(e);
```